# How to change the order of x-axis in multiple boxplots in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to change the order x-axis in this boxplot.

[Now the order is loupe, microscope and video, and I want to change it to microscope, loupe then video]

The dataframe example is like this

```
 Label      Mental Physical Temporal Performance Effort Frustration sum
 Microscope  10     10      10       10     10      10    60
 Microscope  10     10      10       10     10      10    60
 Loupe       20     20      20       20     20      20    120 
 Loupe       20     20      20       20     20      20    120 
 Video       15     15      15       20     20      20    105 
 Video       15     15      15       20     20      20    105
```

This is boxplot i have right now
[boxplot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Og5K.png)

This is my code for ggplot

```
  mydata <- read.csv("boxplotyiyu2.csv",header=TRUE)
  dfm <- melt(mydata, id.var = "Label")
  ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label),width=0.5)+ xlab("Demand") + ylab("NASA-TLX Scores")
```

And I have tried this, but the result is not correct.

```
dfm$variable <- factor(dfm$variable,levels = c("Microscope","Loupe","Video"))
```

Another question is how to modify the y-axis for multiple boxplots.
I have this seven boxplots together, but i want to change the y-axis for each small plot.
[boxplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEm10.png)

(The dataframe is similar with above one, just replace mental,physical...with angle data)

The code I have is

```
  df.m <- melt(mydata, id.var = "Label")
  p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value))
  p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label))
  p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free")
  p <- p + xlab("Angle") + ylab("Degree")
```

Please do me a favor! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Have to give an example dataframe. This may help in the meantime http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/. Sections 3 , 6, 7 and 9 will get you close to what you want.

Comment: Just added sample data frame, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You will need to redefine the order of the factors with the `factor` function.

```
#Sample data
Label<-c("Microscope", "Microscope", "Loupe", "Loupe", "Video", "Video")
mydata<-data.frame(Label)

#print out
levels(mydata$Label)

mydata$Label<-factor(mydata$Label, levels=c("Microscope", "Loupe",  "Video"))
#print out
levels(mydata$Label)
```

See the cookbook-r.com for more information: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/

Comment: Thanks for the reply!